# How to wait until sqlite3 unlocks DB?

Tags: multithreading, shell, sqlite

I am using a one-line script calling the sqlite3 shell to update a value in a DB (this is on Windows 8.1 although that shouldn't matter here).

The script simply reads:

```
sqlite3 < update.sql
```

The update.sql-file contains:

```
.open "mydb.db"
UPDATE <args omitted for brevity>;
.save "mydb.db"
.exit
```

i.e. it opens the DB (according to the sqlite3-help that means: reads it into memory), applies the update and then wants to save the modified DB back to disk again.

But when I execute that script I get:

```
C:\>sqlite3  0<update.sql
.open "mydb.db"
UPDATE <args omitted for brevity>;
.save "mydb.db"
**Error: database is locked**
.exit
```

The reason - as I found out by googling around - seems to be that the UPDATE is run in a background thread, which keeps the DB locked. That means, when the save-command tries to write the DB back to disk, the DB is still locked.

I found no command in the sqlite3-shell to release that lock (or to wait until that lock gets released). So, what can I do to release that lock (or wait until it is released) and thus get this script to work properly?

The absences of such a command and thus the inability to save a DB after applying some modifications seems to make the sqlite3 shell utterly useless to me. I must be missing something fundamental here!?!

Answer (score 0):

I just realized: I don't need to write the DB back, the update already operates directly on the DB. My assumption, that the DB was loaded into memory (and thus also needs to be saved back to disk) was wrong! Apologies for the bandwidth consumed!